# Disable tcp slow start

Tags: ubuntu, tcp

I am looking for disable tcp slow start mechanism for high-speed network. Currently clients send 100MB flows to random servers with non-blocking 1Gbps link. In my math, the completion time of the flows is less than 1 second.

But the problem is that they cannot reach to a full link bandwidth. In other words, they are finished at slow start phase before getting a full link bandwidth. Therefore, I want to increase tcp congestion window size to maximum.

Is there anyone who know how I change that value easily without modification of kernel?

Thx~

Comment: what is your linux kernel version?

Comment: ubuntu 12.04lts and kernel version is Linux user-X9DR3-F 3.2.0-44-generic #69-Ubuntu SMP Thu May 16 17:35:01 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In older Linux kernel versions initial congestion window value (`initcwnd`) was as low as just 2 (2*MSS, or about 3KB), and since 3.0 new default is 10 (about 14KB).

Provided that your Linux kernel is not very ancient, you can increase initial congestion window using command `ip`, something like this:

Get current default route info:

```
$ ip route | grep default
default via 192.168.1.1 dev eth0  proto static
```

Assign new `initcwnd` value to this route:

```
$ sudo ip route change default via 192.168.1.1 dev eth0 proto static initcwnd 10
```

This increases default initial congestion window to higher value of 10*MSS (~14KB). You might want to play with values higher than this, probably as high as 40.

For more information, read [original Google proposal to increase initcwnd](https://developers.google.com/speed/articles/tcp_initcwnd_paper.pdf) and also [this article](http://www.cdnplanet.com/blog/tune-tcp-initcwnd-for-optimum-performance/).